# How can I use 2 Class paint in JFrames generate code by Palette in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

```
public class DrawST extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DrawST
     */
    
    
    public DrawST() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Generated code
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DrawST().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    class Class01 extends JPanel{
       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
       }
    }
    class Class02 extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

How can I use both `Class01` and `Class02` to paint in this JFrame, `Class01` will draw pipes, and `Class02` will draw frog(Happy Frog). I try to create `Container contain = getContentPane();` and add two classes. But it work only 1 class added.If I add two classes, the JFrame won't draw anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a common mistake: creating drawing classes that extend Swing components when they should be *logical* classes, not *component* classes:

- If you're doing animation, usually only *one* component, often a JPanel does the drawing, meaning the `paintComponent` method is overridden in one component.
- If you desire a class to draw a specific sprite, such as a frog, or pipes, then these sprites will be drawn in that same *single* drawing class described above.
- Component classes, classes that extend Swing GUI components such as JPanels are usually placed into the GUI as components -- building blocks of the GUI that are placed in a limited location in the GUI, and that paint themselves and their children only.
- So to do drawings where multiple sprites occupy the same drawing space, the classes that create these sprites should *not* extend JPanel or similar Swing components and instead should only be logical classes (classes that are not components), and then that are drawn by that single drawing JPanel.

For example

```
public class DrawST extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    public DrawST() {
        // add the DrawingPanel to the JFrame here
    }
    
}
```

```
// this class extends JPanel and does *all* the drawing
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private Frog frog = new Frog(0, 0);
    private List<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Timer timer; // you'll probably need a Swing Timer to drive the animation
    
    // a single paintComponent method is present
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  // Don't forget this
        frog.draw(g);  // have this component draw a frog
        for (Pipe pipe : pipes) {
            pipe.draw(g);  // draw all the pipes
        }
    }

}
```

```
// does not extend JPanel
public class Frog {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    public Frog(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // use x, y, and g to draw a frog at x,y location 
    }
}
```

```
// does not extend JPanel (not sure what a pipe is, TBH)
public class Pipe {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    // other? length, color, width?
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // use x, y, and g to draw a pipe. 
        // maybe also needs a length, color, width?
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it was successful, thank you very much!